# PHP displaying wrong image

Tags: php, image, datetime

I've just finished writing my script that changes an image depending on the time. It's all good except it's displaying the wrong image.

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    $w = date('W');                 # week
    $d = date('N');                 # day
    $t = date('G');                     # time


    dealWithTime($d);

    function dealWithTime($day) {
        if ($w == 13) {                 # Week 13
            if ($day == 1) {
                # Monday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 2) {
                # Tuesday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 3) {
                # Wednesday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 4) {
                # Thursday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 5) {
                # Friday
                if ($t >= 2 && $t < 8) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 8 && $t < 12) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 12 && $t < 16) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 16 && $t < 20) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 20) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');     // SHOULD BE THIS ONE
                }
            } else if ($day == 6) {
                # Saturday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18 && $t < 22) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if($t >= 22) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 7) {
                # Sunday
                if ($t >= 2 && $t < 8) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 8 && $t < 12) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 12 && $t < 16) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 16 && $t < 20) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 20) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            }
        } else if ($w == 14) {      # Week 14
            if ($day == 1) {
                # Monday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18 && $t < 22) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 22) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 2) {
                # Tuesday
                if ($t >= 2 && $t < 8) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('Midtown.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('Terminal.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('XD_Holo.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 3) {
                # Wednesday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 4) {
                # Thursday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 5) {
                # Friday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 6) {
                # Saturday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                }
            } else if ($day == 7) {
                # Sunday
                if ($t >= 0 && $t < 6) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 6 && $t < 10) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 10 && $t < 14) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 14 && $t < 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                } else if ($t >= 18) {
                    printImage('fin.png');
                }
            }
        } else {                            # else
            printImage('fin.png');
        }
    }

    function printImage($im) {
        $file = $im;
        $type = 'image/png';
        header('Content-Type:'.$type);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
    }

?>
```

As you scroll down, you should see a comment saying what image it should be (as of this post).

I also wrote another script to see if it was the time that was wrong but it's giving me the correct results.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

    $w = date('W');                 # week
    $d = date('N');                 # day
    $t = date('G');                     # time
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Week:</h2>
        <span><?php echo $w; ?></span>

        <h2>Day:</h2>
        <span><?php echo $d; ?></span>

        <h2>Time:</h2>
        <span><?php echo $t; ?></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first script can be seen here: http://spedwards.cz.cc/event/e.php

And the second here: http://spedwards.cz.cc/event/t.php

I will not be changing these files so they will stay relevant to the question for at least a month.

Could someone please explain to me why the correct image doesn't show? All 4 images are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the variables into the function call.

For example:

```
dealWithTime($w, $d, $t);

function dealWithTime($w, $day, $t) {
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to? I know you don't have to do this in Javascript and Java so I wouldn't think this is any different.

Comment: Javascript and PHP are very different beasts. If you don't want to pass the variables into the function via a parameter but still want to be able to access them, consider using a static variable or use the global scope.

Your problem is explained in detail here: (with solutions)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to PHP as you probably guessed. I just figured it didn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

The return value of the date format functions are strings, you are trying to evaluate them as integers.

You should convert the variables to int using `(int) $d` before evaluating it.

Comment: date('N') returns as an integer between 1 and 7. 1 being Monday and 7 being Sunday. I'm using format characters that return as integers. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Please read the link you shared it says
`Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time().`

I did not notice that you were passing the parameters to the function, but the definitely does not require a down vote.

Comment: var_dump(date('d'));

gives you;

string(2) "30"